# Send a POST request from an Android phone to Visual Studio in localhost

Tags: android, visual-studio, localhost, http-post

I need to send a POST request to my Visual Studio localhost web server using my Android application. I need to do this for debug purposes.

I don't know how to allow my phone to reach the localhost. I tried to use the computer IP address but it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: This question is mis-stated.  Localhost is by definition local - you cannot access it from another machine, because as far as that machine is concerned, *it* and not the remote machine is the localhost.  On an emulator you can access the host machine's loopback interface via an alias (something you cannot do from an actual phone) but that's still not "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to modify your firewall on your computer to allow incoming connections on the necessary port.

Comment: How can i modify the port of the firewall ?

Comment: if from the prowser of the py ehre i have the visual studio running i write 
http://localhost:50445/Default.aspx  it works
but if i write
192.168.1.4:50445/Default.aspx  then it doesn't..  what should i write?

Comment: I got a news from another forum saying:

The "Cassini" web server provided as part of Visual Studio doesn't support requests from any machine other than the one it's running on. 

is this  true ?

Comment: Possible: be quite odd, though. I'm guessing if you are using windows xp you can open port 50445 from the windows firewall control panel applet. If you are using another os like vista or windows 7 or a different security suite like norton then the technique will be different.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used a phone emulator to access locally the localhost server and it worked really well. From the phone, I called the address 10.0.2.2 and it connected to the localhost server.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mis-stated.

Assuming what you want to do is access a server running on your PC:

- You will have the most luck putting the phone and the PC on the same local area (wifi) network.
- You may be able to achieve a local network over USB with some tethering solutions.
- If the PC and the phone are not on a the same local network, the PC will need to have a globally routable IP address, in order for the phone on it's mobile network to be able to reach it.  Many personal ISP solutions do not easily allow for this, due to dynamic IPs, personal routers implementing NAT, or with the IPv4 space being exhausted carrier grade NAT meaning subscribers do not have a unique IPv4 address even temporarily.